# Including "-badge" in the names of tags for badges

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

I think that badge-related tags should be consistently suffixed or not suffixed, but I'm wondering which way people think it should be.

For example, we have [tumbleweed](/questions/tagged/tumbleweed), [unsung-hero](/questions/tagged/unsung-hero), and [nice-answer](/questions/tagged/nice-answer), but also [enthusiast-badge](/questions/tagged/enthusiast-badge), [electorate-badge](/questions/tagged/electorate-badge), and [altruist-badge](/questions/tagged/altruist-badge).

Having "-badge" in the tag name is convenient because it allows the tag selector to suggest all the badges when you enter "badge," but that could also be accomplished via synonyms.

Comment: How would you accomplish that via synonyms? You mean that we would have *both* tags for each badge, with the "-badge" variant as a synonym of the master? That seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Cody I was assuming that having a synonym which included "-badge" would *also* be enough for the tag selector to be able to suggest them, so that either way would be viable.

Comment: @bemace, please don't leave the excerpt detail out of the wiki section on your tag edits.  The wiki section should be complete.  I've been having to edit a bunch of them.

Comment: @bemace, ran out of votes couldn't do them all, will have to fix 'citizen-patrol' when I get home next week.

Comment: @Lance - you mean the body of the tag wiki? I'll try to find something to put in them, though with so many tags having *nothing* I figured just getting the excerpt populated would be a big improvement since it's the most visible part

Comment: @bemace, I mean don't leave the essentials out of the body, just because they're in the excerpt.  Otherwise, they're fine.

Comment: @Lance - ok I get what you mean now; will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should do both, create and retag to the "-badge" tag, and make the non-badge tag a synonym for it.

*But, I don't think we necessarily need to do this for every badge.*