# Should badge tags be renamed for clarity?

Tags: support, tags, meta, clean-up

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Including "-badge" in the names of tags for badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102045/including-badge-in-the-names-of-tags-for-badges)

My current understanding is that tags that refer to badges should be named like this:

> [tagname]-badge

The following tags here on meta don't adhere to that scheme:

- citizen-patrol
- disciplined
- enlightened
- generalist
- mortarboard
- necromancer
- nice-answer
- peer-pressure
- popular-question
- populist
- pundit
- sportsmanship
- taxonomist
- tenacious
- tumbleweed
- unsung-hero
- yearling

Since I can't find the post where I've read about that naming scheme, is that the way they should've been named? I stumbled over the *Taxonomist* tag and thought it should be renamed, but then browsed the tag list and found the list of tags above which don't follow the naming scheme, so I'm not sure now if there really is such a general rule.

Should they all be renamed for clarity?

Comment: Do we really need a tag for every single badge?

Comment: @Strait I can't answer that, and for some other badges I also found that there's a combined tag like [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/editing-badges/synonyms). I was just wondering if the existing ones should be named consistently or not.

Comment: Related: [Including "-badge" in the names of tags for badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102045/including-badge-in-the-names-of-tags-for-badges)

Comment: @bemace Thanks, I didn't find your post when I searched, and I also remember reading about that naming scheme in a different post, more like two months back than two weeks. Is that answer on your post the "official way to go" then? I'd do it, but I haven't got the necessary rep to create tag synonyms, so I can't ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real standard on this, and as you mentioned in the comments some tags cover multiple badges.  The *unofficial* standard a few years ago was just the name of the badge itself.  I think as long as the name is first (so it's found in the dropdown) then everything will be ok.

The key is that the one's without the "-badge" in the name should be unambiguous with any other SE concept/tag.